# How do I archive individual accounts in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm tracking a number of websites on Google Analytics. Some of these sites I'm not actively working on, is there a way to archive the data without deleting the profile / account?

Comment: What do you mean by "archive" ? Google will not delete the accounts, event if you do not use them, so the easiest way is to do nothing. Or do you mean download the data somehow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once data has been inserted into Google Analytics it is written in stone.  There is no way to archive it.   You could delete it but then you will lose the data forever.

If your issue is with seeing accounts that you don't actually use.  You could create a new Google analytics account (email address login type of account) give that email address ownership and then remove your personal accounts ownership.  Then you wont see the account anymore but the data is still stored on your other email account.

Comment: Right - I see. Thanks for the feedback. Much appreciated. I was a little nervous about deleting accounts and losing historic data. 
:)

Comment: I normally just move them to a dummy users its the best way to keep them without having to look at them all the time.